# PHP Application hosted on heroku and Amazon RDS Database connection

Tags: heroku, mysqli, amazon-rds

I have hosted my PHP application on heroku and have set up a database on Amazon RDS.

I have used the following commands to add the DATABASE_URL to Heroku:

```
$ heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password@amazon_rds_endpoint:3306/databasename
$ heroku config:add SHARED_DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:amazon_rds_endpoint@endpoint:3306/databasename
```

I added the security group of Heroku to RDS security with the following credentials:

```
AWS Account ID:098166147350 
EC2 Security Group:default
```

Until the above step I was using

```
mysql_connect("amazon_rds_endpoint","username","password");
```

to connect to the database, which worked fine on the localhost, but when I pushed the code onto Heroku, it gave me an application error.

So I thought of using mysqli function in the following way:

```
$db = new mysqli('amazon_rds_endpoint', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

After using the above code the application loads up but there is neither any error nor any of the lines following the connection code display.

I've started using Heroku for the last couple of days and any help would be great!

**Update:**

When I enabled php errors on my page, I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

But Heroku push tells that I'm using php 5.3.* which should be enough to run mysqli functions.

Comment: Though Heroku has PHP 5.3 for some weird reason they don't include mysqli

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have mysqli support for versions 5.5 and 5.6. You can adding this to you composer.json file:

{
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.12"
  }
}